# CodeIgniter Pagination : uri segment

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I think it's not seems heavenly easy in CI documents shows to users.
I have spend lots of time for find problems and issues. Framework php should be easy and do it fast eh?  That's why they exist?

Here is my code:

```
$config['base_url'] = site_url('admin/index/page/');
$config['uri_segment'] = 4;
```

Mysql Sql Result :

```
SELECT b.*, a.adCampaignTitle FROM ads a, sms b WHERE b.`smsAd_ID`=a.ad_ID LIMIT 4, 20
```

As seen in sql output, uri_segment just acts like a integer value. nothing more. And any page of pagination that creates, sql output is the same !
When i try it like :

```
$offset = $this->uri->segment(4);
```

SQL works fine but pagination ( create links ) does not work properly . 1st page's link disappeared ( just  ) in every page number.

*** Plese post, if you really know something about this issue. I really sick and tired like Anastacia ....

Answer (score 4):

This question is 2 years old. I had a similar problem and googled till this page. Seeing that, it hasnt been answered, in case anyone has a similar problem. You can use

```
$config['uri_segment'] = $this->uri->total_segments();
```

To solve your pagination "links" (Prev,1,2,3,4,Next) error as mentioned above where your first page of pagination will not work properly.

Answer (score 1):

I can't be certain this is your problem, but I believe you need to say how many rows there are as well, for the pagination to work correctly.

So add: `$config["total_rows"] = /*total number of records returned by the query, without the limit */` and see if that helps.

Also read through [this article](http://www.dijexi.com/2009/08/how-to-use-codeigniter-pagination-class-with-database/), for some ideas on how to set it up correctly.

Comment: I won't use obscene language, but WTF? You don't post the entirety of the code, and expect me to infer what the hell you're trying to say? I can get past the broken English, whatever, but see how well berating the person trying to help you works.

Comment: Actually %90 of person asks useless data from me and do not read what i wrote here. Do you know that it is disturbed me at least disturb you while you are trying to help some person. Because I am stuck this pagination issue for a days and can't find proper solution . 
And i said :
$config['base_url'] = site_url('admin/index/page/');
$config['uri_segment'] = 4;

Do i need more proper English to describe my problem ? If you need proper English go to literature dept or something ... It's obvious that you are here for not help people.

Comment: @onder: a word of advice. Be respectful to the people who are trying to help. You aren't paying them.

Comment: @itachi , ppl whose aim not helping and wasting time here ( mostly %90 of people ) Should also be respectful and really need to try help to other people ! So respecting can be gain both of side.

Answer (score 0):

Im using HMVC and I'm having the same issue with pagination to work. But I managed to make it work using HMVC or just MVC in CI by using the segment 3. When I'm using segment 4 it doesn't work. I dont know why. Thats also my big problem because I really need to use the segment number 4. I home this bug can be resolved in the next release of CI.

Answer (score 0):

HMVC using: segment diffrent problem

Link: [domain].com/admin/logs/log_list/10/1

solved:

```
$config['uri_segment'] = 5;
```

Full code:

```
public function data_count($sql){

    $query  = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->num_rows();

}

public function get_list($sql,$url,$show,$page){

    $list = array();
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $total = $this->data_count($sql);

    $config = array(
        'base_url'          => $url,
        'total_rows'        => $total,
        'per_page'          => $show,
        'num_links'         => 5,
        'use_page_numbers'  => true,
        'page_query_string' => false,
        'uri_segment'       => 5,
        'full_tag_open'     => '<ul class="pagination pull-right">',
        'full_tag_close'    => '</ul>',
        'first_link'        => '<<',
        'first_tag_open'    => '<li>',
        'first_tag_close'   => '</li>',
        'last_link'         => '>>',
        'last_tag_open'     => '<li>',
        'last_tag_close'    => '</li>',
        'next_link'         => '>',
        'next_tag_open'     => '<li>',
        'next_tag_close'    => '</li>',
        'prev_link'         => '<',
        'prev_tag_open'     => '<li>',
        'prev_tag_close'    => '</li>',
        'cur_tag_open'      => '<li class="active"><a>',
        'cur_tag_close'     => '</a></li>',
        'num_tag_open'      => '<li>',
        'num_tag_close'     => '</li>'
    );


    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $pagination = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $list["pagination"] =$pagination;

    if(!empty($page)){ $start = ($page*$show)-$show; } else { $start = 0; } 

    $query  = $this->db->query($sql." limit ".$start." , ".$show);

    if($query->num_rows()>0){
        $list["list"] = $query->result_array();
    }
    else{
        $list["list"] = "";
    }

    $list["total"] = $total;

    return $list;

}
```